# How to parse google places json

Tags: android, json, google-api

I an trying to Parse the json results of google places api. I called it using http method and I got the json results back in string
How can I parse it ? I reas the doc and vistited the two blogs on the internet( one uses google api library and one seems to be outdated) and didnt help me

I am using the standard java JSONobject and Gson by google, but i am unable to figure out a good way to parse it (i am calling the search places method)
What do you recommend?
Thank u

Hi, sorry for forgetting to show the JSON response:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [
      "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.ca/\"\u003eYellowPages.ca\u003c/a\u003e"
   ],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 45.39318670,
               "lng" : -75.68352930
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 45.40102170,
                  "lng" : -75.66752190
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 45.38535060,
                  "lng" : -75.69953670
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
         "id" : "6a3f8ef9aae04c8a23c80ab814e8c75a8b685292",
         "name" : "Old Ottawa South",
         "reference" : "adsadada",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ],
         "vicinity" : "Ottawa"
      },
   {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 45.394630,
               "lng" : -75.6837250
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/movies-71.png",
         "id" : "59519a28667351790456ab80aba982347546b2f6",
         "name" : "Mayfair Theatre",
         "rating" : 4.10,
         "reference" : "dfdsf",
         "types" : [ "movie_theater", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1074 Bank Street, Ottawa"
      }
  ]
}
```

I want to grab the results portion  (and lets says the first item of the results only for simplicity)and what i did was the following:

```
JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response);
String result = jso.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).toString();
JsonPlacesResult d = new Gson().fromJson(result, JsonPlacesResult.class);


where JsonPlacesResult is

class JsonPlacesResult{

    private JsonPlaces jsonPlaces;


    public JsonPlaces getJsonPlaces(){return jsonPlaces;}



}
class JsonHtml{
    private String html_attribution;

}
class JsonPlaces{
    private Geometry geo;
    private String icon;
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String rating;
    private String reference;
    private String types;
    private String vicinity;
}
class Geometry{
    private JsonLocation loc;
}
class JsonLocation{
    private String lat;
    private String lng;
}
```

I am ending up with null object in d??? Why is this! what did  I do wrong
Thanks

Comment: Can you add the json you receive so that we do not need to search for it ourselves?

Comment: Here is a tutorial showing you how to parse a JSON String into Java objects using GSON. http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Answer (score 2):

You can learn from these links. Very simple example shown in these links. And post sample of JSON that you received for more clear answer from people. Thanks.

http://[www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/)

http://[www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/)

Comment: I posted a sample as suggested

Answer (score 0):

3 mistakes:
1.the type of "lat" and "lng" should be **float** instead of **String**;
2.the type of "html_attributions" should be **List（String）** instead of **String**;
3.the type of "types" should be **List（String）** instead of **String**;
Sorry for my poor English.