# How to Parse from the JSON file?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have following objects in JSON file. I have to parse it and store it in a file. What will be the android code for doing this?

```
 {
  "result":"ok",
  "numbers":
           [
            {
              "First":"first",
              "Second":"second",
              "Third":"third",
              "Fourth":"fourth",
              "Fifth":"fifth"
            }
           ]
 }
```

Any one find me getting out of this? I would really appreciate your work.

Comment: post your parsing code here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: 1st jsonobject from return string..then get the "number" jsonarray from it..at last get again jsonobject and then get each strings...

Comment: @Anish : take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897820/parsing-json-response-from-google-direction-api/21898535#21898535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ -> json object 
  "result":"ok", 
  "numbers":[-> json array 
            {
```

Do like this

```
JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jarray=Jobject.getJSONArray("numbers");
String result=jobject.getJSONObject("result");
for(int i=0;jarray.length();i++){
      String first= jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("First");
      String Second= jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Second");
}
```

Comment: is "jsonString" the "url of JSON"?

Comment: it is the reponse from the url

Comment: @AnishPanthi if its url then you need to first get the json from the url make a http request

Answer (score 2):

```
 { // json object node
  "result":"ok", 
  "numbers":[// json array numbers
            {
              "First":"first",
```

To parse

```
JSONObject jb = new JSONObject("your json");
String result = (JSONArray)jb.getString("result");
JSONArray jr = (JSONArray)jb.getJSONArray("numbers");
JSONObject jb1= (JSONObject) jr.getJSONObject(0); 
String first = jb1.getString("First");
// similarly for second third and fourth
```

Once you parse you can write the result to a file.

Edit:

Note:  Network operation must be done in a background thread. Use `Asynctask`

```
try
{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("your json url ");  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 
}catch(Exception e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now use _response `JSONObject jb = new JSONObject("_response);`. Rest all is the same

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the following

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject json = null;
JSONArray jsonArray = null;
String data = null;

json = new JSONObject(response);
data = json.getString("numbers");
jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
String str =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

always remember { means object and [ means array so you can proceed with following code in the give

```
JSONObject firstjobject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray firstjarray=firstjobject.getJSONArray("numbers");
String result=firstjobject.getJSONObject("result");
for(int i=0;firstjarray.length();i++){
      String first= firstjarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("First");
      String Second= firstjarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Second");
}
```

here numbers is an array and First,Second etc are the keys for relative data values